# how solve error on create laravel new project?

Tags: laravel

[image]

How solve error on create laravel new project? Please help.

Comment: post your errors as **text** not image.

Comment: did you read the errors messages and done what they said to fix it ?

Comment: Update your php version. You have some `missing php extensions`

Comment: update not help

Comment: Try to use laravel homestead vagrant box. PHP development on windows with OpenServer (or other software) may be painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just edit php.ini and uncomment this line:

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Comment: what is your web server? are you using apache?

Comment: i use openserver

Comment: i'm sorry you right this help me. Thank you so much